# How to add dynamic og tag in server less react app

Tags: reactjs

I want to add dynamic og tag into server less react app.

I had tried using react-helmet but i.e. not working for me.

```
<Helmet>
    <meta property='og:title' content={data.title} />
    <meta property='og:url' content={data.url} />
    <meta property='og:description' content={data.description} />
</Helmet>
```

please help..